# Remove [] from content

Tags: php

I need to remove `[masterslider id="?"]` from my content.The id field is dynamic like

```
[masterslider id="161"]
```

Home of Jodhp Couples exchanging their vows here as well as their guests can also pamper themselves with rejuvenating signature treatments and therapies at the Jiva Grande Spa, or soothe their mind and body with yoga and meditation.`[masterslider id="69"]`.
I tried

```
 $content=preg_replace('/[[\s\S]+?]/', '', $items['post_content']);
```

Comment: What is that text in the middle of your question ? Looks like some hidden spam inside a question

Comment: That seems to be the example.

Comment: Could you add and example of your expected result? The title says `Remove []` and the content says remove `[masterslider id="?"]`.

Comment: Just the paragraph.the whole [masterslider id="161"] from the content need to be remove

Answer (score 1):

You might try:

```
$content=preg_replace('/\[.*?\]/', '', $items['post_content']);`
```

Example with Explanation:
https://regex101.com/r/0GudyD/1

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`$content=preg_replace('/\[masterslider\s*id=".*?"\]/', '', $items['post_content']);`

Explanation :

```
preg_replace('/\[masterslider\s*id=".*?"\]/', '', $items['post_content']);
^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     1                     2                 3              4
```

(1) `preg_replace` is a function that use **Regular Expression** instead of static string (basicly it's a extended version of `str_replace`)

(2) `\[masterslider\s*=".*?"\]` this regex (search/2nd param on `str_replace`) will match [matchslider id="(any id[or string])"]

(3) `''` this is the replacement (replace/3rd param on `str_replace`)

(4) `$items['post_content']` is the subject (text/1st param on `str_replace`)

sorry for my bad explanation

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it